# Binding 'this' in the loop of an array

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, this

I have a Javascript function with a namespace and I am using Prototype to execute a function. Example code:

```
GUI.Title = {
 initialise: function() {
  var elements = $$('a');

  this.show(); /* now it refers to the namespace */

  elements.each(function(element) {
   this.show(); /* this refers to the window object, not to the namespace */
  });

},
 show: function() {
  element.show();
 }
}
```

'this' refers to the namespace outside the each-function and inside the each it refers to the window.

Can someone explain to me how I can use 'this' in the each-loop as a referer to the namespace?

I am using Prototype.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use Prototype's `bind` method to modify what `this` means inside the function.

```
elements.each(function(element) {
   this.show();
}.bind(this));
```

Comment: +1, because your answer is prototype specific. -- i edited my answer to indicate that my answer is more a general javascript way of doing it.

Comment: Note that in the future (not too far, I hope), this will be a valid "javascript way of doing it", `bind` is now part of the ECMAScript 5th Edition Spec. :)

Comment: Many thanks, I knew about 'bind', but I did not know the syntax in relation to solve this issue! Now I know, thanks :) Sometimes the Prototype manual is a little bit hard to understand...

Answer (score 7):

replace

```
this.show(); /* now it refers to the namespace */

elements.each(function(element) {
   this.show(); /* this refers to the window object, not to the namespace */
});
```

with

```
var scope = this;
elements.each(function(element) {
   scope.show(); /* this refers to the window object, not to the namespace */
});
```

what you are doing is creating a closure, the 'scope' var gets 'closed-in' to your each function lexically.  Note that this approach is not prototype specific, it's a general javascript technique.

Comment: This would work. Since Prototype is available, `bind` is a bit neater. Gave you an upvote since it's useful to anyone reading who isn't using Prototype.